# For an elliptic curve E, does there exist a cofinite Fuchsian group without elliptic elements with quotient E minus a finite subset

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, hyperbolic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

Let $E$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus 1, i.e., an elliptic curve.

Let $P$ be the identity element of $E$.

**Question 1.** Does there exist a cofinite Fuchsian group (or a Fuchsian group of the first kind) $\Gamma$ such that $E-\{P\}=\Gamma\backslash\mathfrak{h}$, where $\mathfrak{h}$ denotes the complex upperhalf plane, and $E$ can be obtained by adding the ''cusp'' $P$?

**Question 2.** Does there exist a cofinite Fuchsian group $\Gamma$ without elliptic elements and a finite set of points $\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\}\subset E$ such that $E-\{b_1,\ldots,b_n\} =\Gamma\backslash\mathfrak{h}$ and $E$ can be obtained by adding the ''cusps'' $b_i$.

If yes, how are these groups related to $E$? What can be said about them?

I would like to choose $b_1,b_2,b_3$ and $b_4$ to be the ramification points of the projection onto the $x$-coordinate, i.e., Weierstrass P-function.

Comment: the answer to both question is yes, by the uniformization theorem (for *any* choice $b_1,\dots,b_n$ ($n>0$) it will give you a $\Gamma$ acting freely, i.e. without elliptic elements).

Comment: And this Gamma will be a discrete subgroup of SL_2(R) of finite volume because....?

Comment: It (i.e. finite volume) is true for any compact Riemann surface with finitely many points removed. The proof boils down to showing that a loop around any of the removed points corresponds to a parabolic transformation.